# Does the Vale have a merchant marine?

Tags: game-of-thrones

As per the wikia entry for [the Vale](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Vale_of_Arryn) the more the temperature drops, less accessible it becomes. And, *winter is coming*. So, is there a fleet of ships based in the Vale that normally sails to Essos and southern Westeros for trading purposes? And come winter, that merchant marine will become the primary means of getting food, etc. into the Vale? Or, are not many ships based in the Vale and the Vale relies on traders to sail their ships to the Vale?

The Vale assets are critical for the Northern campaign. Yet they are at dire risk of getting snowed-in soon enough... right?

Comment: Gulltown is a major port, so I assume there's heavy boat traffic in/out of it, but I don't know that we've ever heard of a Vale navy...

Comment: @KutuluMike We have heard of [Vale Navy](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_in_the_waters_off_Gulltown) although not in the current timeline. Visenya Targaryen destroyed a naval fleet of King of Vale and Mountain during conquest

Comment: Northmen have also destroyed Vale navy during [War Across the Water](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/War_Across_the_Water)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Inaccessibility of Vale

Vale is separated from mainland Westeros by a mountain range called [Mountains of the Moon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Mountains_of_the_Moon). The hold of House Arryn on the mountains is contested by [Clans of Mountain](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Vale_mountain_clans) who reject authority of Arryns to rule them. To connect Vale with rest of the Westeros, there is a road running in the Mountains which is called [the High Road](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/High_road). This road leads to a pass on which castle of [Bloody Gate](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Bloody_Gate) guards entry into Vale proper. Since the High Road runs on the Mountains, its availability is subject to weather. In Winter, it is closed to heavy snowing, thus blocking the only land route to Vale. You can see the terrain in the map below:

[image]

### Fertility of Vale of Arryn

The Valley of the Vale is famously fertile. It is a tranquil land of wide rivers and hundreds of lakes. Wheat, corn, barley, pumpkins, and fruit grow in its fertile soil. Vale of Arryn is independent in production of food. Even Highgarden cannot match the quality and numbers of Vale's food production.

### Untouched Harvest

Vale did not take any part in the War of the five Kings therefore it did not have to suffer the dire impacts and losses as other regions did. Riverlands were burnt by both Lannisters and Starks, destroying their crops and harvest. Westerlands were burnt by Starks. Crownlands also saw ravaging at hands of the Northmen. To sum it all up, most regions lost their harvests as a result of war except the Vale and the Reach. Dorne is also untouched by war. In any case, due to their neutrality, Vale did not suffer wide scale burning and pillaging. It is a tradition in Westeros to set aside food for Winter when harvest is not possible. Therefore, in all likelihood, Vale has ample stores for coming Winter.

### Naval arm of Vale

All the great Houses traditionally maintain a naval fleet. Starks had one as well but it was burnt by [Brandon the Burner](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Brandon_Stark_(Burner)). After that Starks never formed their naval arm.

In any case, we have heard about Navy of Vale although not in current timeline. During North-Vale war before the conquest, Arryn and Stark navies [clashed against each other](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/War_Across_the_Water). Later, during Aegon's conquest, Arryn Navy [thwarted Targaryen naval attempt](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_in_the_waters_off_Gulltown) to seize Gulltown, although they got destroyed themselves by Visenya Targaryen and her dragon Vhagar.

It is not clear whether Arryns formed a navy after that or not but it is very likely.

### Gulltown

[Gulltown](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Gulltown) is one of the greatest ports in the realm. It lies strategically on trade route from Braavos to Kingslanding. Therefore many ships traveling to and from Essos anchor in Gulltown to take supplies and for trade. It is the largest city in the Vale.

Petyr Baelish said this about the port:

> "... Gulltown, the Vale's greatest port."

According to [AFFC Chapter 41](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Gulltown):

> Its strategic location means it never lacks for trade in many of the
>   exotic goods making their way from across the narrow sea, **keeping
>   the Vale supplied even when the passes of the Mountains of the Moon
>   are closed in winter**

So it would make sense that given the importance of the city to Vale, House Arryn would maintain a naval fleet there for both trade and security. Even if House Arryn itself does not do that, the ruling [House Grafton](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Grafton) would maintain a fleet there just like Manderlys maintain a fleet a White Harbour, Redwynes maintain a fleet at their port etc.

So in all probability, when the mountain passes are closed due to snow, Vale would be able to ferry supplies and men across the Bite into the North. It must be noted however that Baelish supported North because he hoped to marry Sansa. Now that Sansa has spurned Baelish, it is unclear whether the alliance between North and Vale continue.

But if you are looking for a Canon answer, not informed speculation, the answer would be **We do not know if Vale has a merchant navy from Canon sources**.

Comment: I don't think Sansa spurned Baelish at all. Rather than have him thrown out the "moon door", Sansa saved him by lying. She also let Baelish kiss her.

Comment: @khyle She spurned little finger in this season. She did not let him kiss her this season. And when he told her his dreams about holding Iron Throne and making Sansa his queen, Sansa said it was a pretty picture and went away